# Play Framework Configuration parameters

Tags: playframework

Is it possible to reuse configuration parameters within Play to do something like this?

```
mongodb.host=localhost
mongodb.port=27017

mongodb.servers = [mongodb.host]
```

I want to get the value from mongodb.host and reuse it within mongodb.servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as seen in the [Play Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Configuration)

```
mongo.host=localhost
mongo.port=27017

mongo.servers = ${mongo.host}
```

You can also use system environment variables.